# implicit QueryStringBindable java.util.List[models.InputTimeSheetDataStore]

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Hi i am trying to pass a list of objects of type `models.InputTimeSheetDataStore` from view to application.java and i am getting `No QueryString binder found for type java.util.List[models.InputTimeSheetDataStore]. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type` error

in application.java i am passing list of object to view

```
InputTimeSheetDataStore ITSDS= new InputTimeSheetDataStore();
            ITSDS.ConsultantName=EmployeeFilter;
            ITSDS.Client=ClientFilter;
            ITSDS.Project=ProjectFilter;
            ITSDS.Role=EmployeeRoleFilter;
            ITSDS.Task=Task;
            ITSDS.TimeSheetDate=TimeSheetDate;
            ITSDS.Hours=TaskHours;
            ITSDS.IsBilled=IsBilled;
            ITSDS.Workplace=WorkPlace;
            InputTimeSheetList.add(ITSDS);
            return ok(TimeSheetInput.render(Consultant.PopulateConsultant(),Client.PopulateClient(),Project.PopulateProject(ClientFilter),
                    Consultant.PopulateConsultantRole(),Consultant.ConsultantRoleRate(EmployeeRoleFilter),InputTimeSheetList));
```

in view i am passing that object back to application.java

```
@(EmployeeList:java.util.List[String],ClientList:java.util.List[String],
  ProjectList:java.util.List[String],EmployeeRoleList: java.util.List[String],Rate:String,
  CurrentPage:List[InputTimeSheetDataStore])

  <form id="TimeSheetEntryForm" name="TimeSheetEntryForm" action="@{routes.Application.save("name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name",CurrentPage)}" method="GET">
<code.....>
```

here is my class file

InputTimeSheetDataStore.java

```
package models;


public class InputTimeSheetDataStore {

    public String ConsultantName;
    public String Client;
    public String Project;
    public String Role;
    public String Task;
    public String TimeSheetDate;
    public String Hours;
    public String IsBilled;
    public String Workplace;

    public String  getConsultantName(){
        return this.ConsultantName;
    }
    public String  getClient(){
        return this.Client;
    }
    public String  getProject(){
        return this.Project;
    }
    public String  getRole(){
        return this.Role;
    }
    public String  getTask(){
        return this.Task;
    }
    public String  getTimeSheetDate(){
        return this.TimeSheetDate;
    }
    public String  getHours(){
        return this.Hours;
    }
    public String  getIsBilled(){
        return this.IsBilled;
    }
    public String  getWorkPlace(){
        return this.Workplace;
    }

}
```

my routes is

```
GET     /Application/save            controllers.Application.save(EmployeeFilter:String,ClientFilter:String,ProjectFilter:String, EmployeeRoleFilter:String,Task:String,TaskHours:String,TimeSheetDate:String,IsBilled:String,WorkPlace:String,CurrentPage:java.util.List[models.InputTimeSheetDataStore])
```

can someone help me with the implicit querybinder of type InputTimeSheetDataStore

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you didn't implement `QueryStringBindable<InputTimeSheetDataStore >` in your model?

Comment: @Adam i am not getting how to implement it and seeking help for the same

Comment: ok, could you provide example URL to show what currentPage param should represent?

Comment: @Adam have edited the question

Comment: Please see the relevant documentation page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the example implementation of QueryStringbindable:

```
    public class InputTimeSheetDataStore implements QueryStringBindable<InputTimeSheetDataStore> {

      public String consultantName, client, project;

      @Override
      public Optional bind(String key, Map data) {
        if (data.containsKey("consultantName")) {
            this. consultantName = data.get("consultantName").toString();
        }

        if (data.containsKey("client")) {
            this.client = data.get("client").toString();
        }

        if (data.containsKey("project")) {
            this.project = data.get("project").toString();
        }

        return Optional.of(this);
      }

      @Override
      public String unbind(String key) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public String javascriptUnbind() {
        return null;
      }
   }
```

Extra tips for you, when writing a programming language, make sure you are following the code convention. For example: the convention in Java syntax you must write variable with lower case for the first character;

```
public String ConsultantName; // this is wrong
public String consultantName; //this is right
```

Hope it helps.